# Tweaking traditional quicksort worst cases

Tags: algorithm-analysis

All the sources I find on the internet say the time complexity of quick sort is worse if:

> - input array is sorted and we choose the leftmost element as the pivot
> - input array is sorted reversely and we choose the rightmost element as the pivot

I am wondering if time complexity is still $O(n^2)$ if we do the following instead.

- input array is sorted and we choose the rightmost element as the pivot
- input array is sorted reversely and we choose the leftmost element as the pivot

Does it even matter at the end of the day, we are choosing two extreme-sized partitions?

Comment: yes, it would still be $O(n^{2})$

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort's behavior is bad when every partition is imbalanced (instead of splitting $m$ elements in two, the split is like $1$ vs. $m-1$), leading to $O(n^2)$. A good pivot is one which has a rank close to the median ($O(n\log n)$). In case of an already sorted array, the middle element would be a good choice.